# Javascript in sharepoint not working

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I have been tasked with taking an expense report list and adding an approve all button that will change the drop down of each item in the list to approved. I am working through several tutorials on how to use javascript inside sharepoint but i am banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why my code is not running. I have added an asp:button to a asp:content area, and a script tag with a function in it. See below:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Approve All" id="approvebutton" OnClientClick="dosomething()"></asp:Button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function dosomething()
    {

        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext();
        //var olist = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('b612de4b-f85c-4492-8877-8c2b07ae187d');
        //clientContext.load(olist);
        //clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        //  Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        //  Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
        //  );

        alert("Should be done");
        //$("#{26787EDD-BCDC-41D2-ABEE-249747203BE8}-{69F3E959-EB93-458F-A4CD-E1ACA2335D10}").hide("slow");
        //$("#ctl00_onetidHeadbnnr2").hide("slow");



    }

    //function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args)
    //{
    //          
    //      alert("Title: " + olist.get_title()));  
    //}
    //function onQueryFailed(sender, args)
    //{
    //  alert("Request failed");
    //}


</script>
```

If all i have in my function is the alert, the code works, but as soon as i add the first line, the SP.ClientContext() line in, it breaks. Nothing executes after it and i cant figure out why. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the `SP.ClientContext` on wrong way.

See the [Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx)
and [SP.ClientContext object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj245759.aspx) on MSDN

Anyway you can use the **ClientContext** in two way:

1. `var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();` for getting the current context if you are inside a Sharepoint Page
2. `var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);` for create a new context with arbitrary url

Another tips is to wait until sp.js is loaded

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);
```

See the example on MSDN page of second link or see this [sharepoint.stackexchange.com article](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/60522/executeordelayuntilscriptloaded-not-executing-after-page-publish)

Comment: A mixture of this, as well as changing where i was loading the sp.js file. I had it in the sub page, but went back and put the reference in the master page and it started working. thanks!